# Different the width of whitespace in eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse

I set my editor use the whitespace only, but I got problem with the whitespace's width. The longer whitespace in blank lines, shorter in others. I have no idea how to configure it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a variable width font. Change it to a fixed width font like Courier New/Consolas/Monaco/Menlo (depending on your preferences)

Go to Eclipse->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->Structured Text Editors->Structured Text Editor font and set it to a fixed width font

Answer (score 1):

If you *do* want to use a variable width font, just make all those fonts/colors use the same size.

Monospaced fonts are only used because editors still don't support relatively recent inventions like [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/) which results in the type of issue you highlight. That plus habit.

I personally find that variable width fonts look *so* much better and increase the readability *so* much that they're totally worth it.