# Eclipse code formatting is not aligning fields in columns properly

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

Eclipse code formatter is not aligning fields equally with **Align fields in columns** option checked when field is of type `int` or `boolean`. Here's how it shows up after formatting:

```
    private Rect                mTempRect;

    private int                     lastClickX;
    private int                     lastClickY;

    private int                     mMaxLinesCount;
    private boolean                 mWrapped;
    private boolean                 expanded;
    private SpannableString     mLinkHideText;
```

I'm using Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 JUNO x64, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits.

Comment: Is formatting set up to use tabs or spaces or both?

Comment: Try making it spaces and see what happens.

Comment: Did you have spaces as tabs or some mixed tab/space format for tabs?

Comment: Eeek, aligned columns. I just tried it in Eclipse (4.2.1 Juno Win 7 x64) and it worked for those lines you pasted (and I have it set to spaces). Edit: it's broken in mixed mode but works in tabs only mode

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It got almost aligned but some field names went 1 space left or right. It's strange, now I can't align the fields even manually because it seems the letters' widths have different sizes.

Comment: @h3nr1x Where do you mean this configuration is located?

Comment: We have a new feature about this on Eclipse 4.9 -> https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was that Eclipse was using a variable width font so that white spaces got different widths when code formatted. Solved changing the font to a fixed size one.

Reference: [Different the width of whitespace in eclipse editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126073/different-the-width-of-whitespace-in-eclipse-editor)

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

1. Go to Window --> Preferences --> General --> Appearance --> Colors and Fonts and then to Basic --> Text Font
2. Change font from Monospace 8 to Liberation Mono 8.

That works for me.

Comment: That's what the answer already states, although "Monospace" is already... monospace.