# Eclipse Java Formatter - Align Fields in Columns; Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, format

My java formatter - 'Align Fields in Columns' is not working. Hopefully I'm doing something wrong that I can correct. This is how I have it set currently...

**EDIT:** Looks like it's an option limitation of the formater. It will work when it's in the class itself but not when it's in a method inside a class :(

Font: `Courier New` + Tabs only selected as you can see:

[image: java formatter]

And this is how it looks after I select all -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Problematic part from lines 56 to 61. Is there some sort of limitation where it doesn't see those lines and I need to do something differently?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503309/eclipse-code-formatting-is-not-aligning-fields-in-columns-properly

Comment: Yeah I read that before posting this actually. Im in a mono-space font (Courier new) and Im using tabs only already. The problem isnt that it5 isnt doing it *well* its that it isnt doing it *at all*

Answer (score 1):

It says "fields", which I do believe means "variable declarations of a class". Line 56-61 obviously looks like variable declarations of a method. Thats probably why they aren't formatted at all.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse fail to align fields with tab only.
If you want to keep tab indentation you can use this settings :

> Tab policy: Mixed
>   Indentation size: 4
>   Tab size: 4
>   [X] Align
>   fields in columns